# Why am I getting undefined for my variable in the controller but it displays correctly in the HTML page with data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why am I getting values with data binding from my with `{{myItem}}` but in my controller when I try to assign  a new variable I get or output to console I get `undefined`.

This is my controller:

```
var controllers = angular.module("myItem.controllers", []);
controllers.controller('myItemController', function ($scope, MyItemService) {
    $scope.version_model = null;
    $scope.itemGroup_model = null;
    $scope.item_model = null;

    $scope.myItem = null;
    $scope.versions = null;
    $scope.itemGroups = null;
    $scope.hierarchies = null;

    $scope.init = function () {

        $scope.myItem = MyItemService.getMyItem();
        console.log("myItem => id= " + $scope.myItem.versionID + " requestTypeID: " + $scope.myItem.requestTypeID);
        $scope.versions = MyItemService.getVersions();
        $scope.version_model = $scope.myItem.versionID;
        console.log("version_model :" + $scope.version_model + "scope.myItem.versionID : " + $scope.myItem.versionID);

        $scope.itemGroups = MyItemService.getItemGroups();
        $scope.itemGroup_model = $scope.myItem.itemGroup;
        console.log("itemGroup_model :" + $scope.itemGroup_model + " scope.myItem.itemGroup : " + $scope.myItem.itemGroup);

        $scope.hierarchies = MyItemService.getItemList($scope.itemGroup_model);
        $scope.item_model = $scope.myItem.itemName;
        console.log("item_model :" + $scope.item_model + " scope.myItem.itemName : " + $scope.myItem.itemName);
    }

    $scope.getItems = function (group) {
        $scope.hierarchies = MyItemService.getHierarchyList(group);
    }
```

any time I try to assign anything from $scope.myitem I keep getting undefined. I have tried setting inside the init, out side the init., everything works on my page except for where the `_model` values are undefined, once I interact with someting and it gets updated all works fine, just not on initialization

**Update**

this is what my service looks like

```
angular.module('servicefactories', [])
    .factory('MyItemService', function ($http, $q) {
    obj.getMyItem= function () {
        var mypromise = $q.defer();
        $http.get('getforEdit')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            mypromise.resolve(data);
        });

        return mypromise.promise;
    }

    return obj;

});
```

Comment: Most probable cause may be asyn nature of call made to get myItem

Comment: @chandermani would you have any suggestions to counteract this?

Comment: Is this call async `MyItemService.getMyItem();`

Comment: @Chandermani I have added a snippit of my service so you can see exactly what I am doing

Comment: Please see my answer. It seems to be clearly a async issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected this is issue with async call. You can use the `then` method on promise to access the data and assign once data comes from server. Something like

```
MyItemService.getMyItem().then(function(data) {
         $scope.myItem=data;
         console.log("myItem => id= " + $scope.myItem.versionID + " requestTypeID: " + $scope.myItem.requestTypeID);
        $scope.versions = MyItemService.getVersions();
        $scope.version_model = $scope.myItem.versionID;
        console.log("version_model :" + $scope.version_model + "scope.myItem.versionID : " + $scope.myItem.versionID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

call your function:
$scope.init();

In your code init function do not run on initialize controller. You must call it manually.

Comment: that only half solved the problem, I can see it in my page now But, the `_model` values are still undefined

Comment: you shure in $scope.myItem have values versionID and itemName?
versionID -- string or object?

Comment: I am sure yes, all Strings, data binding to page with `{{workflow.VersionID}}` works